# VisualBrush makes Visual blurred

Tags: c#-4.0, wpf-controls, visualbrush

i have a problem with the WPF `VisualBrush`. [Here](http://1drv.ms/1qkLHzr) you find two images from my application. The bigger on is a image which shows a control with text. The smaller one is a extract from the first on who i use a visual brush to make it. My problem is, that when the resolution of my Visual (the content for `VisualBrush`) would be smaller then the visual brush looks more blurred. I don't no why. I use the following code to declare the visual brush.

```
 var blendBrush = new VisualBrush
        {
            Visual = Host.Viewer,
            TileMode = TileMode.None,
            AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left,
            AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top,
            Stretch = Stretch.None,
            ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
        };
```

`Host.Viewer` is the control you see it on the big image. Everytime the control size is changed i update the `ViewBox` values with the following routine:

```
var viewBox = new System.Windows.Rect(topLeft, new Size(width, height));
        visualBrush.Viewbox = viewBox;
```

`topLeft` is the start coordinates and the `width` and `height` values are the size of extract i needed. 
I hope anyone can help how i can prevent that the control would be blurry!

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found the problem. `Host.Viewer` contains in deeply part a canvas which contains a image object. Images could look blurry in .NET 4.0 and higher. The problem could resolve to set `UseLayoutRounding = true;` and `BitmapScalingMode = BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor;` for the `Canvas` and the Rootparent-object.